# Python failed to locate the file or directory when it's created and already iterated through other 498 items

Tags: python, loops, file, for-loop

I'm kinda new with Python and I'm not really sure what's going on.
I'm iterating through files in the following way.

```
for link in links_dir.glob('*.pkl'):
```

It runs just fine for the first 498 files until this one arrives:

**'Concejalía de Servicios Generales, Medio Ambiente, Deportes y Tercera Edad del Ayuntamiento de Granadilla de Abona1.pkl'**

I check that the folder exists (which does, and if it doesn't it is created). I've also tried to remove the commas, accents and other characters, but none of this worked.

However, the next files are received just fine. Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: So you are searching `links_dir`. Does your script throw an error? Have you tried renaming this file to something shorter, like 'Concejalia1.pkl'?

Comment: I have being testing it and I think the issue is related to the length of the name of the file yes. Thank you tho :D

Comment: De nada! But have in mind that depending on the OS of yours, long filenames might cause an error with the function reading the file.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Yes, I have a Windows OS, so it has a 260 char limit pathwise, but the weird thing is that the number of characters in the path that gave the error is 230. It is close to the limit but that makes me think that it might be something related to how pickle reads the document and the length of the filename itself. Thanks again!